# Insert character after every 3 characters in string

Tags: c, pointers

For every three characters copied from str1 to str2, the character ch is inserted into str2.

```
(Input1) Enter a string:  abc de 
(Input2) Enter a character to be inserted: # 
Output: abc# de
```

Code:

```
void insertChar(char *str1, char *str2, char ch) 
{
    int i, j, count = 0, flag = 0;
    char *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3;
    ptr1 = str1; //Input string
    ptr3 = &str2; //char string array output

    for (i = 0, j = 0;*ptr1 != '\0'; ptr1++, i++, j++, ptr3++)
    {
        str2[j] = str1[i];
        if (*ptr1 == ' ' && flag != 1)
            ++count;

        if (flag != 1 && count%3)
        {
            flag = 1;
            for(ptr2 = ch;*ptr2 != '\0'; ptr2++)
            {
                str2[++j] = *ptr2;
                ptr3++;
            }
            str2[++j] = ' ';
            ptr3++;
        }
    }
    str2[j] = '\0';
}
```

However my code is unable to run. May I know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comment, there are some issues with the code.

```
ptr3 = &str2
```

In this line, you are not assigning the string to `ptr3`. Rather you are assigning the address of the pointer that contains the start address of the string. For example: Suppose the first character in your string is located in address location 1000. Then, `str3` contains the value 1000. However, `str3` itself will be located somewhere else. Let's suppose it is located at 2000. Then, `ptr3` contains the value 2000 and after increment, it will point to 2001 and so on. Thus, you get wrong and dangerous values.

There is also a problem in the line `for(ptr2 = ch;*ptr2 != '\0'; ptr2++)`. You are assigning the value of ch to ptr2. This should give you a warning. Again, the memory pointed to by ptr2 is changed. So, *ptr2 tries to dereference that memory location.

The code I would use for this:

```
void insertChar(char *str1, char *str2, char ch) {
    int count = 0;
    while (*str1) {
        *str2++ = *str1++;
        ++count;
        if (count == 3) {
            *str2++ = ch;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    *str2 = '\0';
}
```

Some recommendations:

- Try to declare the variables as close to their usage as possible.
- Use `-Wall` option when compiling your programs